# How can i put formclosing event in Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button called `btnChallenge`. The desired action is when it is clicked, the form cannot be closed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void btnChallenge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // not sure on this if statement
    if (btnChallenge.Click)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea was you're asking here.

Comment: You want a button, which, when clicked, prevents the form from closing?

Comment: i want the button (btnChallenge ) make the formclosing event
 e.cancel = true
then the form1 can't be closed

Comment: i want the form cant be closed if the user click on chellange button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a variable which goes to true when you press the button and check on close if the variable is true

e.g.

```
private bool btnClicked = false;
public void btnChallenge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btnClicked = true;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(btnClicked)
    {
        e.Cancel=true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try it this way:

Declare a private variable inside a form:

```
private bool _closedFromMyButton;
```

Then on `FormClosing` event check that property:

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_closedFromMyButton) // If closed from MyButton, don't do anything. let the form close.
        return;
    Hide(); // Hide the form (or not, it's up to you; this is useful if application has an icon in the tray)
    e.Cancel = true; // Cancel form closing
}
```

Then on some button click (if desired), put this code to close the form only from that button (or menuitem or toolbar button, etc.):

```
private void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _closedFromMyButton = true;
    Application.Exit(); // Or this.Close() if you just want to close the form.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `this.Close()` method, this will call the `Form1_FormClosing` event:

```
public void btnChallenge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the users by closing your form just after they have pressed some other button, then this code will help you.

```
private bool close_state=false;    // hold the button state

// method to change the close_state by button click
private void Button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    close_state = true;
    // if required you can toggle the close_state using an if statement
}

// Then on FormClosing event check that property:

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (close_state) {// If the button is pressed
        e.Cancel = true; // Cancel form closing
    }
}
```

You may implement some other way to close the form....